# How to read from and write to a Unix domain socket in Pharo?

Tags: utf-8, smalltalk, pharo

my application needs to read and write to a [Unix domain socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket). How can I do that from Pharo?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do it with the Socket library. The primitives have `AF_INET` hard-coded in the calls to `socket()` (you need `AF_LOCAL`). Also, there is no way to set the `sun_path` field of the `struct sockaddr_un` that gets passed to `connect()`.

It looks like you'll have to use FFI or write your own plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the new SocketPlugin primitives allow to access all socket families, not just AF_INET. I know it can do AF_INET6 besides AF_INET for sure, and I'm almost sure it can do all others as well. Pharo may be lacking the new in-image code to access those primitives, I don't know. But e.g. Squeak Etoys was using them on the OLPC XO machine to do IPv6 mesh networking.

Comment: Cool! Are there new primitives, or were the old one enhanced? And how long ago? I have fairly recent (~1 month) sources from gitorious and, for example, sqSocketCreateNetTypeSocketTypeRecvBytesSendBytesSemaIDReadSemaIDWriteSemaID hardcodes INET and fails if the type is TCP or UDP

Comment: Thanks Bert. Is there any Squeak image with these primitives? I tried the latest etoys image but was not able to open it due to a missing 'squeak' executable (why Squeak is not in etoys?).

Comment: Damien: If you are referring to Etoys-To-Go from http://squeakland.org/download/ then the includes etoys.sh script should run it fine. There is a Squeak VM we just renamed the binary to "etoys" so it stands out in a process list.

Comment: Sean: Yes, there are new primitives, in addition to the old ones, so the same plugin can serve old and new images. I see for example a method SocketAddressInformation class>>addressFamilyLocal in addition to #addressFamilyINET4 and addressFamilyINET6 which must be good for something.

Comment: Bert: where does SocketAddressInformation live? I don't see it in Squeak 4.3 or Pharo 2.0... only Etoys?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently someone implement it recently: http://samadhiweb.com/blog/2013.07.27.unixdomainsockets.html

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.